# How can I add my view to specific perspective?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I had implemented two plugins. One is for perspective and the other is for view.

The class for the perspective MyPerspectiveFactory which id is my.MyPerspective.

And my view plugin xml is the following. It means add my view short cut to the my perspective.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
<perspectiveExtension targetID="my.MyPerspective">
           <view
             id="my.myview"
             ratio="1"
             relationship="stack"
             relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList">
           </view>
           <viewShortcut
             id="my.myview">
           </viewShortcut>
         </perspectiveExtension>
 </extension>
```

This shortcut does not work.

If I change targetID to * or org.eclipse.cdt.ui.CPerspective, It works fine in the C/C++ perspective.

Please let me know your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the correctness of the ids (is it really my.MyPerspective or my.myPerspective? or similar) and make sure the TaskList view is available in the perspective.